# Cannot display a NSString in detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring

I can add text to my `UITableView`, but when I try to add to `detailTextLabel` a certain string that used to be a `NSDate`, the app crashes and says:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate isEqualToString:]:
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8383690'
```

I can add a regular dummy `NSString` to `detailTextLabel`, so I don't get it.  Any help?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSString* temp = [biggerDateA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = [bigA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [biggerDateA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Date Goes here";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = temp;

    [bigA retain];
    //[biggerDateA retain];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: "A string that used to be a NSDate"? What do you mean?

Comment: Are you sure that `certain string` is of `string` type?

Comment: What type of objects does `biggerDateA` hold? Looks like `NSDate` objects. And of course you can't set the `text` property to a date.

Comment: You are almost certainly attempting to assign an NSDate to a label.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
NSString* temp = [biggerDateA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Even though *you* declare this is an `NSString`, what matters is what it *is*. And what it is, is an `NSDate`.

You need it to be an `NSString`, but then you must explicitly convert it, probably by passing through an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: @ZachLucas Please mark matt's answer or Mayank's one as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using following code by converting to `NSDate` to `NSString`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSDate* date = [biggerDateA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *temp = [format date];
    cell.textLabel.text = [bigA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = temp;
    [bigA retain];
    //[biggerDateA retain];
    return cell;
}
```